# C++ Syntax error - identifier not found

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

I have a file "injectdll.h", code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>

void GetTargetThreadIdFromProcname(char *procName);

bool LoadDll(char *procName, char *dllName);
```

And a file "injectdll.cpp" with following code:

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "injectdll.h"

void GetTargetThreadIdFromProcname(char *procName)
{
} 

bool LoadDll(char *procName, char *dllName)
{
    GetTargetThreadIdFromProcName(procName);
}
```

I cannot compile that simple piece of code:

> error C3861: "GetTargetThreadIdFromProcName": Bezeichner wurde nicht gefunden. / 'identifier': identifier not found, even with argument-dependent lookup

Where's the error? It's driving me crazy...

Comment: `GetTargetThreadIdFromProcName != GetTargetThreadIdFromProcname`

Answer (score 8):

You have camel-case ProcName in the call; the function is declared as Procname

Comment: There are times one should use copy and paste ... this is one of them! :)

Answer (score 1):

In your posted code you have a capital on `...ProcName` when you call it from within `LoadDLL`.

Comment: LOL ... thanks guys! This was the first thing I cecked but reading is hard =)

Comment: Especially if you've been staring a the screen for hours :)

Comment: @omg: When this kind of thing happens cut/paste the error into the search box and see if it will find the name.

Comment: @Tux-D: but make sure you've selected case-sensitive ;)